# Flask Python Registration doesn't work properly

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have this register form on my flask webapp, which checks  if an username is already registered or not. For some reason when I register, it redirects me to my home.html (Which means im logged in), and also gives me a `flash("Error. Username already exists")`back. Why does it go into the `except:` and then in the `finally`? I'm not quite sure how to fix that. I've checked my database as well. My user information is saved on there.

Thats my code:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        with sql.connect(DATABASE) as con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            try:
                # flash("register attempted")

                username = request.form['username']
                password = pwd_context.encrypt((str(request.form['password'])))
                email = request.form['email']

                cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name,password,email) VALUES (?,?,?)",(username,password,email) )
                con.commit()
                flash ("Successfully registrated")
            except:
                con.rollback()
                flash("Error. Username already exists")
                return redirect(url_for("register"))

            finally:
                session['logged_in'] = True
                session['username'] = username
                gc.collect()
                return render_template("home.html")
                con.close()
```

**EDIT:**

```
x = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?"),(username)

                    if int(len(x))  > 0:
                        flash("Error. Username already exists")
                        return redirect(url_for("register"))
                    else:
                    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name,password,email) VALUES (?,?,?)", (username, password, email))
                    con.commit()
                    flash("Successfully registrated")
                    session['logged_in'] = True
                    session['username'] = username
                    gc.collect()
                    msg = Message('Hello', sender='yourId@gmail.com', recipients=[email])
                    msg.body = "your username for ak047 is: %s and your password is %s" % (request.form['username'],request.form['passwordd'])
                    mail.send(msg)
                    return render_template("home.html", msg=msg)
                    con.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not catching **any** particular exception. If your code inside your `try` block throws **any** exception, for example that `request.form['email']` was null and you tried to insert it into a non-null column, it would throw an exception that would cause your code in the `except` block to run. Even an `IndexError` would cause this to run. So any error will result in the `flash("Error. Username already exists")` line to execute.

The code in the `finally` block will always run.

Have a look at [error handling in Python.](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/exception-handling) In particular on catching specific errors. It is a very useful thing to get right.

If you want to know exactly what exception is being thrown, you could do something like:

```
try:
    ....
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    ....
```

This catches any exception and stores the exception and thusly the stack trace in the variable `e`, ready to be printed out or logged to stdout.

Once you know that your code is, for example, throwing an `IndexError`, or a `NotNull` error, or whatever error it might be, you can write error specific code to launch depending on the error, for example:

```
try:
    ....
except IndexError:
    # Do some code if there is an IndexError in the try block
except NotNull:
    # Do some code if your db throws a not null error when trying to insert something in the try block
finally:
    # Always run the code in here...
```

Comment: But in my code I have `con.rollback()`doesn't that cancel the SQL Query

Comment: I've edited my post. Will the new code work properly?

Comment: Tough to tell... Bar the indentation issues; there was an error that your original code was throwing that you never worked out. Like I said in my answer, it could well have been in the SQL insert... I still think you should catch `Exception` and log the stack trace. The try-catch model is better suited for what you are doing.